# Добавление библиотек в проект в IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Имеется некоторый проект. В нем содержится `pom.xml`, в котором описаны зависимости.

Проект создается в `Intellij IDEA`.

Как добавить библиотеки к проекту, чтобы они скачались и подцепились в IDE, чтобы в дальнейшем не возникало проблем типа "класс не найден".

Конечно. В `IDEA` обычно при добавлении зависимостей в `pom` файлик появляется надпись с `Auto-import` для maven. В итоге жмем туда и все библиотеки успешно добавляются в проект.

А как сделать тоже самое, только из командной строки(используя даже ту, которая в самой IDE) средствами `maven`?

Comment: Я не понимаю вопроса. В командной строке требуется сделать что? Отредактировать `pom.xml` файл?

Comment: @JBaruch, в командной строке выполнить команду `mvn "что-то там"` чтобы `jar` файлы библиотек описанных в dependency добавились в папку с проектом. IDEA может и сама выполнить данные вещи, но все-таки хотелось понять как именно с помощью `mvn` данную операцию.

Comment: А, понял, сейчас отвечу

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы Maven скачал зависимости, достаточно дёрнуть любую фазу [цикла](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) для которой вы хотите зависимости получить. Т.е. если вам нужны зависимости в `compile` scope, то нужно дернуть `mvn compile` или любую фазу позже `compile`.